# Dynamic colors API is not working on Android sdk 32

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui

I have a simple android app which I would like implement dynamic color from material 3. I use Google guideline (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apply-dynamic-color#0) (I override onCreate() in Application class and I add this class in android manifest), and dynamic color is working on emulator (sdk 31/32/33), however on physical device is not work (sdk 32). And if I to add colors-v31 in project and override color, it's work on phone. What could be the problem? Do I understand correctly that it is not necessary to override color resources for dynamic colors?

**Application.kt**

```
class Application: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(this)
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    <activity>
        android:exported="true"
    </activity>
    <!-- others xmls tags -->
</appication>
```

In themes.xml I use parent Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar and colors from material theme builder

Screenshots of how it's now and how it should be: [color is pink, but application is green (default color for this app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfxi0.jpg)
[green app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExuEM.jpg)
and how app should be: [if color system is orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFsGz.png)
[and app is orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugdze.png)

if i override colors in v-31 it work. but i was read android devs codelabs and i think it is not necessary to override colors

Comment: It should work without color override . I have `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar` for light theme and `Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar` for night mode .. It works well for me on device running on 12.

Comment: @ADM yes, thank for answer, this problem is due to the launcher of my phone, it probably does not work correctly, on pixel 6 everything works correctly with android 13

Answer (score 0):

These palettes are specific to `Android 12 (API 31)` so you will need to place relevant files in folders with a `-v31` suffix unless your app has a **minimum SDK set to 31 or higher.**

Also in your `AndroidManifest.xml file` specify an explicit value for `android:exported` for the activity.

```
<application>
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:exported="true">
 <!-- others xmls tags -->
</application>
```

Comment: thank for answer, but this problem is due to the launcher of my phone, it probably does not work correctly, on pixel 6 everything works correctly with android 13